# Flutter emotion recognizer api?

Tags: flutter, cross-platform, face-detection, azure-cognitive-services

I'm developing an android app which use azure for emotion recognition in kotlin, but  I would like to know if a similar alternative exists using flutter.

The only alternative I've found so far is [this](https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_mobile_vision), but catch only the happiness, and not several emotion like azure does.

Does anybody know a way for emotion recognition using flutter? thanks in advice

Comment: Why not use azure API then ?

Comment: Are available for dart language? @RémiRousselet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use Azure for image recognition which is written in Kotlin. 
You need to implement that API natively in your android code using platform channel provided by the flutter. 
Through platform channels, you can implement any native API or SDK which is not available in Dart and its pretty easy and can be used for many purposes such as implementing payment gateways and native APIs.
Here's the official documentation for [Platform Channel](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the Mobile Vision API, which is the on-device version. On-device detection is a bit limited. Instead what you should use is ML-Kit to detect faces. 
ML-Kit Flutter Package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_ml_vision

Hope this helped!